# How to remove common name=value pair from first file when compared with other file

Tags: batch-file

I have two .properties files as follows

```
    first.properties                    second.properties
    -----------------                   ---------------------
    firstname=firstvalue                fourthname=fourthvalue
    secondname=secondvalue              sixthname=sixthvalue
    thirdname=thirdvalue                nineththname=ninethvalue
    fourthname=fourthvalue              tenthname=tenthvalue
    fifthname=fifthvalue
    sixthname=sixthvalue
    seventhname=seventhvalue
```

i want to compare two files and need to remove common name-value pair from first.properties.
The output file should be as

```
    third.properties.
    ------------------ 
    firstname=firstvalue                
    secondname=secondvalue              
    thirdname=thirdvalue            
    fifthname=fifthvalue
    seventhname=seventhvalue
```

i used the following code,but it is giving Cartesian product scenario.can you please help me out to achieve the above.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%E in (first.properties) do (
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G in (second.properties) do (
    if "%%E" NEQ "%%G" echo %%E=%%F>>!HOME!\Properties\third.properties
    )
    )
```

Comment: Made an edit to remove the "echo" from the `echo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
findstr /vg:second.properties first.properties>third.properties
```

Comment: Thanks Endoro for your response,It is working for both the files are in same folder.what if the two properties files in different folders.?how can we include the path in for loop logic?

Comment: The value for the value as said above is also getting changed.Here it is checking for only exact strings.when ever the value changes for a name it is not working.How can we handle this also?

Comment: This was not the question. Please do **not** enhance questions, make new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Be very careful that you explain your task fully.
With the new information, this works here.

```
@echo off
pushd "d:\folder"
copy /y "first.properties" "third.properties" >nul
for /f "delims==" %%a in (' type "second.properties" ') do (
find /v /i "%%a=" <"third.properties" > "third.properties.tmp"
move /y "third.properties.tmp" "third.properties" >nul
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `>>`? also, shouldn't MOVE be outside the loop? Why not let FOR /F read the file directly since that is more efficient? The strategy using FIND may fail if a name exists as a substring of another name or within a value.

Comment: It's not efficient, it just does the job. :)  It does filter on the = so it the values also contain equals then it's not 100%.

Comment: But "third.properties.tmp" gets over-written and moved on each iteration. The end result is at most one line in the final version, when perhaps there should be many.

Comment: Try it, Dave.  The file is filtered into a tmp file, and the tmp file replaces the source file.

Comment: OMG, I can be dense sometimes. It works perfectly as advertised. +1, and thanks for your patience.